# Where can I find lists of predator-prey relationships?

Tags: data-request, biology

There are many web sites that define predator-prey relationships and give a small number of examples.  I also saw this post [Where can I find biological time series data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6767/14851) but that seems to be more focused on the number of predators vs the number of prey as a time-series. I just want the relations like

```
pelicans eat trout; 
trout eat mullet
eagles eat rattlesnakes
rattlesnakes eat mice
mice eat beetles
```

But I would like this for a large number of animals.  Does anyone know of a long list?

Comment: might be able to do this with a Sparql query on Wikidata, https://query.wikidata.org, but will need a pro user (in particular, this node https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q170430 )

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a good source for this type of data. In the data sets associated with the [Pajek Project](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pajek/) you can find links to these [FoodWeb Datasets](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/bio/foodweb/foodweb.htm). The actual relationships are given by indices, but there is a key for decoding them. For example, in the cypdry.paj file,   `15  39` means that Great Blue Herons eat Crayfish. You will have to do some work, but the information is there.